# Duplicate page content and the Google index

Tags: google-search

I have a static pages with dynamically expanding content that google is indexing. I also have deep links into virtually duplicate pages which will pre-expand the relevant section of content into the relevant section.

It seems like Google is ignoring all my specialized pages and not putting them in the index. Even after going through web-masters tools, crawling and submitting them to the index manually.

I also use the google API for integrating search on the site, and the deep linked pages won't show up. Is there a good solution for this?

Comment: How long has it been since the first crawl? Submitting a sitemap doesn't necessary mean they have or will be indexed. It can take a month and several crawls before they might be indexed, if a new site then it could be sandboxed. Sharing the website would be helpful.

Comment: @bybe We've submitted all URLs outside of webmaster tools around a month ago. I submitted it directly on webmaster tools a few days ago. There's quota to immediately request a re-index using the web masters tools which should take somewhere short of 24 hours.

Comment: Word to take note is `request`, Google can and regularly does take time to index content. But to rule out a problem with your site your going to need to provide more details or provide the website address... as no one can help you with the little information you have provided.

Comment: @bybe No it's not just a request, it's a realtime submission for a re-index. Matts Cutts talked about it in 2012 (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_by8sNaaHIU) and that you could do it up to 50 times a week (10 times for sitemaps). It's the *normal* indexing process that takes variable hours, days, weeks.

Comment: Yes, re-index... I lost count how many times Matt Cutts mentioned the words update a page! There is no instant way to get new pages to appear in the index, you can encoverage it by adding backlinks and social mentions. Submitting a sitemap, submitting a site and so on isn't fast and you enter a queue system. Important and big sites get more priority than new, and old sites that are deemed not high priority.

Comment: And again, your gonna have to provide more details as currently the question is duplicate with the vast amount of Ajax and dynamic questions and answers already on Pro Webmasters. Furthermore it's impossible to answer your question, answers like mine are mere guesses due to not seeing the way your site works or providing source code on a page that isn't being indexed.

Comment: It will be much easier to say something sensible if you tell us which site this is about.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing rate is a function of how often the content changes, how valuable the content is in the eyes of search engines and how many valuable backlinks there is to your site. If some of your content is duplicate or near duplicate, then it is unlikely to be indexed, no matter what. You need to use canonical wherever possible for such content.

Besides, get more backlinks and traffic to your site if possible. I am also assuming your site is not suffering from one of the [typical issues](http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/site-not-indexing-checklist.html) preventing it from being indexed.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it.